# Request limit exceeded screen on Magento Cloud

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4, fastly

Suddenly I started to have the message below on my Magento 2.4.4 Cloud.

```
Request limit exceeded
```

Is it something from the CDN side or from Magento?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Fastly security option, it's configured to block bots scrapping your content, you can avoid it by disabling this option in the image below.

[image: Magento 2 Fastly Rate Limiting]